# Type error with function using tuples and lists

Tags: haskell

The problem code follows below.

```
type Point = (Float, Float)
xs = []
arrange_in_pairs :: Point -> Point -> [Point] -> [(Point, Point)]
arrange_in_pairs (x, y) (xi, yi) points 
    | length xs == 0 = xs ++ [((x, y), (points !! 0))]
    | (length xs - 1) /= length points = xs ++ [((points !! (length xs - 1)), (points !! length xs))] arrange_in_pairs (x, y) (xi, yi) points
    | otherwise = xs ++ [((points !! length xs), (xi, yi))] xs
```

The idea is a point is a co-ordinate like on a graph. (x, y) is the starting point, (xi, yi) is the end point and "points" is a list of points in between them. The function is supposed to take each pair of points as a tuple and store them in a list. so the first tuple is (x, y) and the first point in "points". the second tuple is the first point in "points" and the second point in "points" and so on until the last tuple in the list is the last point in "points" and (xi, yi). Any help really appreciated.

the error im getting is:

```
*** Expression     : [(points !! (length xs - 1),points !! length xs)] arrange_in_pairs (x,y) (xi,yi) points
*** Term           : [(points !! (length xs - 1),points !! length xs)]
*** Type           : [((Float,Float),(Float,Float))]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

Comment: Remember that variables are immutable in Haskell, so no matter what you do, that global `xs` will always be an empty list. Instead of trying to mutate a global, you need to recursively define the list as the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> so the first tuple is (x, y) and the first point in "points". the second tuple is the first point in "points" and the second point in "points" and so on until the last tuple in the list is the last point in "points" and (xi, yi).

There is a function `zip` with type,

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

which pairs the elements of two lists position-wise. Also you can build lists,

```
list1 = [(x, y)] ++ points  
list2 = points ++ [(xi,yi)]
```

once you have that, you're really close.

Comment: to follow up then, why does this return an error? it says the equals is unexpected.

`arrange_in_pairs :: Point -> Point -> [Point] -> [(Point, Point)]`
`arrange_in_pairs (x, y) (xi, yi) points`
` list1 = [(x, y)] ++ points`
` list2 = points ++ [(xi, yi)]`

Comment: @JoeWalsh The equals is unexpected because you can't just define variables like that in the middle of your function. You need to use a `let` or `where`.

Comment: @DarthFennec both let and where come up as unexpected as well. im not enjoying haskell very much

Comment: @JoeWalsh I  gave you  piece for you to build your program. You can build what you asked for in the quoted text using `zip` and `[(x, y)] ++ points` and `points ++ [(xi,yi)]`. You don't have to define the auxiliary lists, but if you want to then you need to know the basics of how to use `let` or `where`.

Comment: @JoeWalsh Perhaps you need to read a tutorial (for example, [this one](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where)). You can't just toss code in willy-nilly and expect the language to know what you mean, you need to follow some basic syntactic structure. This is true for every programming language, not just Haskell.

Comment: @Joe Walsh in any case if you want to try it out, the solution I was leading you towards is `zip ([(x, y)] ++ points) (points ++ [(xi,yi)])`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because of this line:

```
[((points !! (length xs - 1)), (points !! length xs))] arrange_in_pairs (x, y) (xi, yi) points
```

When you put spaces between things in Haskell, it means you're calling a function. In this case, the first part of the line:

```
[((points !! (length xs - 1)), (points !! length xs))]
```

is being interpreted as a function, being called with four arguments:

```
arrange_in_pairs
(x, y)
(xi, yi)
points
```

This is why it says `Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d -> e`. It's expecting a function that takes four arguments and returns a value, but instead it sees a value of type `[((Float,Float),(Float,Float))]`.

---

I think what you're trying to do here is use `xs ++ [...]` to update the value of `xs`, and then return a value `arrange_in_pairs (x, y) (xi, yi) points`, perhaps? There are a number of things wrong with this:

- As stated, just putting a space between the two pieces of code doesn't work. Haskell interprets that as function application.
- The `++` operator does not update values, it simply concatenates two lists and returns the result. `xs` does not change if you do this.
- Indeed, in Haskell all variables are immutable, so if you define an `xs = []` in the global scope it will never have any value other than `[]`. You need to use a different approach, such as recursion.
- The value you're returning is a recursive call with unaltered arguments. This is equivalent to a loop that never increments its counter: it will loop forever and never get any work done.

---

@JorgeAdriano mentioned a more concise solution, but I don't think it really helps much with understanding the principles. If I were to do this problem, my approach would be to try a recursive function. To do this, you need two things:

- A base case: What do we return if `points` is empty?
- A recursive case: We can use the first element of `points` to decide what the first element of the result should be, and we can also call the function again with different arguments so that it gives us the rest of the output.

Recursive functions over lists depend on the cons (`:`) constructor. I bring this up because I notice you don't use it in your code, but it's quite important:

- `x:xs` returns a list where the first element is `x`, and the rest of the elements are the elements in the list `xs`.
- When used as an argument (in a pattern match), `x:xs` binds the first element of the list argument to `x`, and the rest of the elements to the list `xs`. If the list is empty, `x:xs` does not match.
- When used as an argument (in a pattern match), `[]` matches only if the list is empty.

---

The base case (`points` is empty) is that a single segment from the starting to the ending point is returned. This can be written:

```
arrange_in_pairs start end [] = [(start, end)]
```

The recursive case is more complicated. We know the first element needs to be a segment from the starting point to the first element in `points`, so we can begin with this:

```
arrange_in_pairs start end (x:xs) = (start, x) : ???
```

Instead of binding the third argument to `points`, we're binding its first element to `x` and the rest to the list `xs`. The return value is the first element (a segment from `start` to `x`), consed to the rest of the elements (a list we haven't defined yet).

So far, so good. The `???` should be a recursive call to `arrange_in_pairs`, and it should be called in such a way that the first segment it returns is the next segment we need. The next segment we need is from `x` to the first element of `xs`, so we need to pass `x` in place of `start` and `xs` in place of `points`:

```
arrange_in_pairs start end (x:xs) = (start, x) : arrange_in_pairs x end xs
```

The full function looks like this:

```
arrange_in_pairs :: Point -> Point -> [Point] -> [(Point, Point)]
arrange_in_pairs start end [] = [(start, end)]
arrange_in_pairs start end (x:xs) = (start, x) : arrange_in_pairs x end xs
```